# oop Check if return type is parent or child class

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Suppose I have this class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name {get; set;}
}
```

and this class, which inherits from Parent:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string Toys {get; set;}
}
```

In some random class, I have a function that returns Parent:

```
public class SomeClass
{
    public Parent GetPerson()
    {
      if (whatever)
      {
        return new Parent { Name = 'Parent' };
      }
      else
      {
        return new Child {Name = 'Child', Toys = 'Paper Plane, Spider Man'};
      }
    }
}
```

when I call this GetPerson, I want to know if it is a Parent or a Child.
I thought this might work, but this condition is always false

```
var person = GetPerson();

if (person is Child childPerson) // This is always false :(
{
   var toys = childPerson.Toys;
}
```

Comment: Maybe condition is always `true`?

Comment: What's the actual condition?  Does your method ever *return* a child?

Comment: Is there a typo in your last code block? You have `var foo...` but then check `if (person...`. Did you mean to do `if (foo..`?

Comment: YES, sorry, typo. Fixed it now.

Comment: What is the condition `whatever`?

Comment: It is not relevant. that function could return either one or another.

Comment: But in your case it's relevant, if condition is always `true` (inside `GetPerson()`) then everything works well

Comment: ok, then assume the GetPerson() method always returns a Child  (return new Child {Name = 'Child', Toys = 'Paper Plane, Spider Man'};) The condition still fails.

Comment: If `whatever` is false then the condition should succeed.  We need a [mcve] that reproduces the issue, not assumptions.

Comment: did you try using GetType() on person object?

Comment: @RomanDoskoch so sorry, you are right. I was looking at the bad breakpoint :( There is no issue afterall, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

I copied and pasted the "if" statement and it does return true when person is in fact "Child" type. Make sure that person's type is indeed of type child at the time you enter the if condition. This would presume that GetPerson(); always returns a parent.

Comment: OMG I am so ashamed. I've put the wrong breakpoint. There is no issue afterall. So sorry to have consumed your time. Thanks guys :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you try **GetType()** and **typeof()**?

Example:

```
if (person.GetType() == typeof(Child))
{
   ...
}
```

Regards

Comment: why this is better?

Comment: Actually is the "same way" to compare, I've just posted another way to do it. I prefer use **is** instead of GetType()/typeof(). I always heard using "is" is faster than GetType. What do you think?

Comment: No, it isn't the same way. There is significant difference between these two constructions. The operator `is` ensures that the instance can be converted to specific type which implies applicability to inherited types and types which implement specified type if it's an interface. Your code implies exact comparison so it's definitely not an equivalent of an "is" expression.